# Running huggingface Bert tokenizer on GPU

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I'm dealing with a huge text dataset for content classification. I've implemented the distilbert model and distilberttokenizer.from_pretrained() tokenizer..
This tokenizer is taking incredibly long to tokenizer my text data roughly 7 mins for just 14k records and that's because it runs on my CPU.

Is there any way to force the tokenizer to run on my GPU.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65857708/is-there-a-way-to-use-gpu-instead-of-cpu-for-bert-tokenization).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tokenization is string manipulation. It is basically a for loop over a string with a bunch of if-else conditions and dictionary lookups. There is no way this could speed up using a GPU. Basically, the only thing a GPU can do is tensor multiplication and addition. Only problems that can be formulated using tensor operations can be accelerated using a GPU.

The default tokenizers in Huggingface Transformers are implemented in Python. There is a faster version that is implemented in Rust. You can get it either from the standalone package [Huggingface Tokenziers](https://huggingface.co/docs/tokenizers/python/latest) or in newer versions of Transformers, they should be available under [`DistilBertTokenizerFast`](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/distilbert.html?highlight=distilberttokenizerfast#transformers.DistilBertTokenizerFast).

Comment: Thank you. I've implemented the fast tokenizer and the performance has increased dramatically.

Comment: I'm a little confused, https://huggingface.co/docs/tokenizers/python/latest/ states it's got a fast rust implementation, does that mean the python package will use this rust implementation by default? Or perhaps @tehem you could elaborate on what you mean by you implemented the faster tokenizer ? I might be missing something

Comment: How can we use it in multiple CPU cores? Here it is using a single core.